# L'expression « sa propre salive » est-elle une figure de style ?

Tags: expressions, figure-de-style

L'expression *« sa propre salive »* indique-t-elle dans ce contexte une figure de style ou non ?

> [...] ce rituel royal, il signifie la reprise de puissance, de force
>   fécondante, de pouvoir, et d'autant plus clairement qu'il requiert une
>   seconde phase durant laquelle le roi mourant transmet au successeur la
>   Loi des ancêtres royaux et **sa propre salive**, support de tout
>   pouvoir. Il est dépouillé du capital symbolique reçu au temps de son
>   investiture

Ce texte est extrait de *Le Détour: Pouvoir et modernité*, de George Ballandier

Comment: Il serait intéressant de contacter l'auteur, car transmettre sa propre salive (celle qui naît avec la parole et non celle qui vient des réflexes de la bouche) peut aussi signifier transmettre le pouvoir de la parole royale, il ne peut y avoir qu'une bouche royale dans la tribu.

Answer (score 2):

Peut être un pléonasme, puisque "sa salive" devrait suffire.

Cependant rajouter "sa **propre** salive" insiste bien sur le fait qu'il s'agit de la sienne, et pas celle du sucesseur, je suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une quelconque figure de style dans cette phrase. Le roi mourant donne bel et bien à son successeur de la salive, qui elle, en revanche, a un aspect symbolique.

Answer (score 1):

Le terme "propre" devant un "nom" permet d'insister sur la singularité du "nom" à effectuer l'action. Autrement dit, il n'y a aucune autre instance du même type/nature/genre du "nom" exécutant ou participant à l'action faite par le possesseur du "nom".

Exemple 1: J'ai vu un homme tuer un autre par ses propres mains.
Cela signifie que le tueur n'a pas utilisé un(e) autre outil/arme/main d'une autre personne pour faire l'action.

Exemple2: Je t'ai élevé avec mon propre argent.
Cela peut signifier que le parent a dépensé sont argent et non pas de l'argent volé ou l'argent d'une autre personne.

Exemple3: Il l'a vu de ses propres yeux.
Cela signifie que la vision a été effectuée à l’œil nu non par à travers des lunettes ou une vitre par exemple.